# java.text.Collator for String comparison.,

Tags: java, string

Trying to use Collators for validating couple String objects., Here is the code.,

```
String myBubbleStr[] = {"zoon", "Hello", "World", "Yep", "Yow", "MyData"};
    public void testCollatorStrings() {
        Collator collator = Collator.getInstance();
        String toCompare = "yow";
        for (String collatorCompare : myBubbleStr) {
            System.out.println(collator.compare(collatorCompare, toCompare));

        }
    }
```

My expectation of the output is -1,-1,-1,-1,1,-1. 
According to the [documentation](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/text/Collator.html#compare%28java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String%29).

> Returns an integer value. Value is less than zero if source is less
>   than target, value is zero if source and target are equal, value is
>   greater than zero if source is greater than target.

But the output I get is

> 1
>    -1
>    -1
>    -1 1
>   -1

Can somone help, how to get about this validation., The reason am using collators is to over the unicode restrictions for String comparison. Thanks.,

Comment: Much is dependent on locale, strength and decomposition. See [this post](http://illegalargumentexception.blogspot.co.uk/2013/02/java-caseless-strings.html) for some API examples. In the case of natural language sort order is not simple. In some Latin-based alphabet cases Z might come before A. If sorting names, all sorts of bizarre rules might apply.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The output looks correct, because collation order produced by the particular instance of `Collator` considers the case of the letter only for tie-breaking.

- `zoon` is after `yow` alphabetically, so the return value should be `1`
- `Hello` is before `yow` alphabetically, so the return value should be `-1`
- `World` is before `yow` alphabetically, so the return value should be `-1`
- `Yep` is before `yow` alphabetically, so the return value should be `-1`
- `Yow` is the same as `yow` alphabetically, but starts in a capital letter, so the return value should be `1`
- `MyData` is before `yow` alphabetically, so the return value should be `-1`

You can lower collator's strength to make strings that differ only in case evaluate as identical.

Comment: "Yow" in the comparison is returning 1 and not -1. But I get ur explanation of "zoon" comparing to "Yow"

Comment: @SathishJayapal You're right, I copy-pasted the same string, and forgot to all the modifications correctly. Your collator sorts lower case ahead of upper case.